# How to get exclusive skins in Smite?

Tags: smite

In Smite there are many skins you can choose for each hero, but how does one get the skins that say EXCLUSIVE in the picture?

There is not an obvious way of purchasing these skins, I want the one for Ragnatoskr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exclusive skins are only purchaseable during special occasions and probably not via the store.

For the moment, there is the [Humble Bundle](https://www.humblebundle.com/) `E3 2016 Digital Ticket`, where you can get such Exclusive Skins:

[image: humble bundle screenshot]

This is a limited offer until around `June 21st, 2016`.

Comment: Maybe someone could make the image a bit smaller, don't remember the syntax for doing this.

Comment: +1 from me. I think the image size is fine. Makes it easy to read. Then again, I'm on a desktop web client right now. There are other ways to get exclusive skins (on desktop anyway), but they almost all require money or something that represents money. You can purchase chests with gems (which you can early very slowly in-game or buy a lot very quickly). I'm trying to think if there was ever an exclusive skin that you could earn strictly through gameplay, but none come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Exclusive skins are only obtainable through special promotions and chests.

Comment: @Frank The previous answer did not mention chests which is the main source of exclusive skins

Comment: Okay, I missed that.  I retract my statement.